# How to get a percentile rank based on a computation

Tags: sql, oracle

there are four tables as :

1. `T_SALES` has columns like

   ```
   CUST_KEY,
   ITEM_KEY,
   SALE_DATE,
   SALES_DLR_SALES_QTY,
   ORDER_QTY.
   ```
2. `T_CUST` has columns like

   ```
   CUST_KEY,
   CUST_NUM,
   PEER_GRP_ID
   ```
3. `T_PEER_GRP` has columns like

   ```
   PEER_GRP_ID,
   PEER_GRP_DESC,
   PRNT_PEER_GRP_ID
   ```
4. `T_PRNT_PEEER` has columns like

   ```
   PRNT_PEER_GRP_ID,
   PRNT_PEER_DESC
   ```

Now for the above tables, i need to generate a percentile rank of the customer based on the computation `fillrate = SALES_QTY / ORDER_QTY * 100` by peer group within a parent peer.

could someone please help on this?

Comment: Which database do you use. The various ones have different helper methods to help with stuff like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytic function `PERCENT_RANK()` to calculate the percentile rank, as below:

```
SELECT
    t_s.cust_key,
    t_c.cust_num,
    PERCENT_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY (t_s.SALES_DLR_SALES_QTY / ORDER_QTY) DESC) as pr
FROM t_sales t_s
INNER JOIN t_cust t_c ON t_s.cust_key = t_c.cust_key
ORDER BY pr;
```

**Reference**:

[PERCENT_RANK on Oracle® Database SQL Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions109.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If by "percentile rank" you mean "percent rank" (documented [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions109.htm)), then the harder part is the `join`s.  I think this is the basic data that you want for the percentile rank:

```
select t.PEER_GRP_ID, t.PRNT_PEER_GRP_ID,
       sum(SALES_DLR_SALES_QTY * ORDER_QTY) as total
from t_sales s join
     t_customers c
     on s.CUST_KEY = c.cust_key join
     t_peer_grp t
     on t.PEER_GRP_ID = c.PEER_GRP_ID
group by  t.PEER_GRP_ID, t.PRNT_PEER_GRP_ID;
```

You can then calculate the percentile (0 to 100) as:

```
select t.PEER_GRP_ID, t.PRNT_PEER_GRP_ID,
       sum(SALES_DLR_SALES_QTY * ORDER_QTY) as total,
       percentile_rank() over (partition by  t.PRNT_PEER_GRP_ID
                               order by sum(SALES_DLR_SALES_QTY * ORDER_QTY)
                              )
from t_sales s join
     t_customers c
     on s.CUST_KEY = c.cust_key join
     t_peer_grp t
     on t.PEER_GRP_ID = c.PEER_GRP_ID
group by t.PEER_GRP_ID, t.PRNT_PEER_GRP_ID;
```

Note that this mixes analytic functions with aggregation functions.  This can look awkward when you first learn about it.

Comment: thanks for the query linoff,but didnot understand the usage if sum function here ..could you please explain?